# Como chamar uma função dentro dela mesma? Recursividade

Tags: javascript, recursão, google-sheets

### Objetivo

Fazer uma recursividade dentro da função `SALVARHISTO()` para que, seja chamada novamente a função, caso a célula `A8` não seja encontrada.

### O que eu tentei

Tentei colocar uma condição no final, se a célula A8 não estivesse vazia, a função executava até encontrar a célula A8 vazia. Alguém pode me ajudar?

### Código

```
function SALVARHISTO() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A7:L7').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Histórico'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('7:7').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A7').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Produção mensal\'!A7:L7').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBackground('#dbe5f1')
  .setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
  .setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false)
  .setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
  .setBorder(null, null, null, true, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A7').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Produção mensal'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A6').activate();
  
  var x = sheet.getRange('A8');
  if( x != " "){
    function SALVARHISTO(){}
  
  }else{
  return 'Salvo com sucesso.';
  }
  
};
```

Comment: Olá Camilla, se você colocar 3 acentos graves (```) antes e depois do seu código, ele vai ficar `monoespaçado` e mais fácil de ler aqui no StackOverflow.

Comment: Não acho que tentar resolver esse problema assim seja uma boa ideia. Você estará executando essa função `SALVARHISTO` muitas vezes por segundo (talvez dezenas, centenas ou milhares). Colocar um `setTimeOut` de 1 segundo já seria algo melhor, mas talvez seja possível fazer uso de *listeners* para isso.

Comment: Isso `function SALVARHISTO(){}` declara uma função e  não executa a função

Comment: Para você executar uma função com recursividade basta você chamá-la novamente dentro da função. **SALVARHISTO()**. Sem a palavra **function** na frente

Comment: Olá @BrunoCunha, acredito que realmente seja este o problema, será q podes adicionar como resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Para você executar uma função com recursividade basta você chamá-la novamente dentro da função SALVARHISTO() sem a palavra ***function*** na frente, pois function serve para você declarar uma função.

```
function SALVARHISTO() {
  // some code
  if( x != " "){
    SALVARHISTO();  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Para você executar uma função com recursividade basta você chamá-la novamente dentro da função SALVARHISTO() sem a palavra function na frente, pois function serve para você declarar uma função.
>
> ```js
> function SALVARHISTO() {
>  // some code
>  if( x != " "){
>    SALVARHISTO();  
>  }
> }
> ```

O Bruno já deu a resposta ali, sempre que você for apenas **executar** a sua função, você deve invocá-la usando o formato `nomeDaFuncao(parametro)`, sem a palavra reservada `function` na frente.

Porém eu diria para tomar cuidado com a recursividade dada a simplicidade do seu if.
A chance de acontecer um erro do tipo ***stack overflow*** (exceder o limite de chamadas de uma função/método) se você não tiver plena certeza dos possíveis retornos de `.getRange()` pode ser perigosa.